# How to delete spreadsheet after importing in php using spreadsheet reader?

Tags: php, import, spreadsheet

After I am importing a spreadsheet I would like to delete it when I am done. I am using Spreadsheet reader in PHP. I know this is a short description but I dont think I need to post the entire code because there's nothing wrong with the code and if you know how to delete just post an answer.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Comment: @JeremyHarris unlink ( string $filename [, resource $context ] ) : bool   ...you see that comma in  [, resource $context ] ? Could that be a typo?

Comment: No, it is not a typo. It is inside the square brackets meaning it is the next parameter, but also optional.

Comment: @JeremyHarris this did the job unlink($inputFileName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple use Unlink after read like:

```
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example1.xls';
/**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
$inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
/**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
/**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
$spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
//DO WHAT YOU WANT
unlink($inputFileName); // delete file
```